# what does the command `set autolist` do?

Tags: command-line-interface

Any idea what the `autolist` argument means? I could'nt find anything about it in the manual.

Comment: You didn't specify what shell you are using!

Comment: @RonK, Thanks. Always remember to describe your environment when asking questions. BTW, the answer to your question was is in the main tcsh man page. Do you know the key shortcuts to search in the man page viewer?

Comment: @Caleb, No - I don't know how to open the main tcsh man page not to mention how to search in it - I'll be happy to learn.

Comment: You said you couldn't find it in the manual so I wasn't sure what you were reading. You can find the man pages for almost any unix command by running `man command-name`, so you would use `man tcsh` to pull up the manual for your shell. `q` will quit, `j` and `k` will scroll up and down, and if you hit `/` you can enter a search term. After you type in a term, `Enter` to search, then `n` to jump through matches. A google search for "linux man command-name" will almost always [turn up a copy](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh).

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with `man`, but i ran `man set` and not `man tcsh` - until know I did not know I could do that. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `tcsh` setting autolist will cause tab completion to show a menu of options when the completion choice is ambiguous instead of just beeping at you and waiting for more input until an unambiguous completion is possible. From the tcsh man page:

```
autolist (+)
    If set, possibilities are listed after an ambiguous completion.
    If  set  to  `ambiguous', possibilities are listed only when no
    new characters are added by completion.
```